# How to keep format in view but not in model (Currency Directive)

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to format a number to currency while the user typing in the field, which actually changes the control actual value to formatted value`(number to a string)`.

Is there any way to format the number to currency for view purposes only, without changing the control's actual value to string? and keep a "normal" number in the model Because I have another directive that has a min and max value which depends on this control's actual value in number format.

**Input Element:**

```
<input
digitOnly
type="text"
currencyFormatter
[decimal]="false"
id="salary-range"
class="form-control"
formControlName="maxSalary"
placeholder="Enter Max Salary"
[min]="formcontrol['minSalary'].value || 1"
[max]="formcontrol['currency'].value === 'INR'? 100000000: 1000000"
/>
```

**Directive:**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[currencyFormatter]'
})
export class CurrencyFormatterDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(public el: ElementRef, @Self() private ngControl: NgControl) {
        this.inputElement = el.nativeElement;
        this.formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'INR',
            minimumFractionDigits: 0,
            maximumFractionDigits: 0
        });
    }

    private formatter: Intl.NumberFormat;
    private inputElement: HTMLInputElement;
    private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.ngControl.control?.valueChanges
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe(this.updateValue.bind(this));
    }

    updateValue(value: string) {
        let inputVal = value || '';
        const unformatted = this.unformatPrice(inputVal);
        const formatted = this.formatPrice(unformatted);
        this.setValue(formatted);
    }

    private formatPrice(value: number): string {
        return this.formatter.format(value);
    }

    private unformatPrice(value: string): number {
        return new RegExp(/[$₹., ]/g).test(value)
            ? Number(value.substring(1).replace(/,/g, ''))
            : Number(value);
    }

    private setValue(value: string | number): void {
        this.ngControl.control?.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next(true);
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using `ControlValueAccessor`. I have created a component and added the input where I am showing the formatted currency value and with the help of ControlValueAccessor I have sent the actual value.

**Currency Component HTML:**

```
<input
    digitOnly
    type="text"
    [id]="inputId"
    [min]="minValue"
    [max]="maxValue"
    [decimal]="false"
    [isCurrency]="true"
    class="form-control"
    [allowNegatives]="false"
    [formControl]="currency"
    [autocompleteOff]="'off'"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
/>
```

**Currency Component TS:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'currency-input',
    templateUrl: './currency-input.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./currency-input.component.css'],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => CurrencyInputComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class CurrencyInputComponent
    implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor
{
    constructor() {}

    public isDisabled = false;
    @Input('min') minValue!: number;
    @Input('max') maxValue!: number;
    public currencyValue: string = '';
    @Input('input-id') inputId!: string;
    private onTouched: Function = () => {};
    @Input('placeholder') placeholder!: string;
    public onValidationChange: Function = () => {};
    private propagateChange: Function = (_: number) => {};
    private unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
    @Input('currency-format') currencyFormat: 'INR' | 'USD' = 'INR';
    public currency = new FormControl('', {
        nonNullable: true
    });

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.currency.valueChanges
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
                map(this.currencyToNumber),
                tap((value) => {
                    this.setValue(value);
                    this.propagateChange(value);
                })
            )
            .subscribe();
    }

    private numberToCurrency(value: number): string {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat(
            `en-${this.currencyFormat === 'INR' ? 'IN' : 'US'}`,
            {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: this.currencyFormat,
                minimumFractionDigits: 0,
                maximumFractionDigits: 0
            }
        ).format(value);
    }

    private currencyToNumber(value: string): number {
        return new RegExp(/[$₹., ]/g).test(value)
            ? Number(value.substring(1).replace(/,/g, ''))
            : Number(value);
    }

    private setValue(value: number | null): void {
        const formattedValue = !!value ? this.numberToCurrency(value) : '';
        this.currency.patchValue(formattedValue, {
            emitEvent: false
        });
    }

    public writeValue(value: number | null): void {
        this.setValue(value);
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
        this.onValidationChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    public setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        isDisabled ? this.currency.disable() : this.currency.enable();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribe$.next();
        this.unsubscribe$.complete();
    }
}
```